# How to copy/create derived class instance from a pointer to a polymorphic base class?

Tags: c++, class, copy, instance, polymorphism

I have been struggling with this kind of problem for a long time, so I decided to ask here.

```
class Base {
  virtual ~Base();
};
class Derived1 : public Base { ... };
class Derived2 : public Base { ... };
...

// Copies the instance of derived class pointed by the *base pointer
Base* CreateCopy(Base* base);
```

The method should return a dynamically created copy, or at least store the object on stack in some data structure to avoid "returning address of a temporary" problem.

The naive approach to implement the above method would be using multiple `typeid`s or `dynamic_cast`s in a series of if-statements to check for each possible derived type and then use the `new` operator. 
Is there any other, better approach?

P.S.: I know, that the this problem can be avoided using smart pointers, but I am interested in the minimalistic approach, without a bunch of libraries.

Comment: This seems like an exact duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148706/copying-a-polymorphic-object-in-c. See the accepted answer by Michael Anderson there.

Comment: @Darhuuk: I'm not quite sure what the SO policy on duplicates is, but this question is a little different. The OP here asked about the way to solve this problem, whereas the OP of that question asked whether cloning is a good C++ approach. It's obviously related, just not sure if it's an "exact duplicate".

Comment: @Itjax Fair enough, it's just that the answer given there is more or less exactly what the OP is looking for. Although I guess your answer below is even more convenient :).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You add a `virtual Base* clone() const = 0;` in your base class and implement it appropriately in your Derived classes. If your `Base` is not abstract, you can of course call its copy-constructor, but that's a bit dangerous: If you forget to implement it in a derived class, you'll get (probably unwanted) slicing.

If you don't want to duplicate that code, you can use the [CRTP idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to implement the function via a template:

```
template <class Derived>
class DerivationHelper : public Base
{
public:
  virtual Base* clone() const
  {
    return new Derived(static_cast<const Derived&>(*this)); // call the copy ctor.
  }
};

class Derived1 : public DerivationHelper <Derived1> { ... };
class Derived2 : public DerivationHelper <Derived2> { ... };
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to have a pure virtual `CreateCopy()` method in the common base that is implemented in each derived class.

Comment: @David Doria: Yeap, except that snippet leaks memory big time.