# What happens if I "slice" to an abstract class

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

First off, I know the assignment operator cannot be defined in a class that has some subclasses. I understand it is because we don't want to make `Subclass1 = Subclass2` possible.

But let's assume `Class` is an abstract class and `Subclass` is its... ya know. Then, is it feasible to do something like this?

```
Class* p = new Subclass;
Subclass s1;
*p = s1;
```

Actually, I tried implementing that in my code, but it didn't work :)
Could you please help?

My full code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class BadIndex{
    int index;
public:
    BadIndex(int i):index(i){}
    int getIndex(){ return index; }
};

template <typename t>
class Wielomian{
public:
    ~Wielomian(){}
    virtual int getDeg() = 0;
    virtual t& operator [](int) = 0;
    virtual bool operator ==(Wielomian<t>&) = 0;
    virtual Wielomian<t>& operator +(Wielomian<t>&) = 0;
    virtual Wielomian<t>& operator +=(Wielomian<t>&) = 0;
};

template <typename t>
class TabWiel: public Wielomian<t>{
    int deg;
    t* plnml;
public:
    TabWiel(t tab[] = {}, int size = 0);
    ~TabWiel();
    TabWiel(const TabWiel<t>&);
    TabWiel<t>& operator =(const TabWiel<t>&);

    template <typename st>
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& s, TabWiel<st>& tw);                                             
    int getDeg(){ return deg; }
    t& operator [](int);
    bool operator ==(Wielomian<t>&);
    TabWiel<t>& operator +(Wielomian<t>&);
    TabWiel<t>& operator +=(Wielomian<t>&);
};

template <typename t>
TabWiel<t>& TabWiel<t>::operator =(const TabWiel<t>& tw){
    if (this != &tw){
        delete[] plnml;
        deg = tw.deg;
        plnml = new t[deg + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < deg + 1; i++)
            plnml[i] = tw.plnml[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

template <typename t>
TabWiel<t>::TabWiel(t tab[], int size){
    deg = size - 1;
    plnml = new t[deg + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < deg + 1; i++)
        plnml[i] = tab[i];
    if (deg == -1){
        deg = 0;
        plnml[0] = 0;
    }
}

template <typename t>
TabWiel<t>::~TabWiel(){
    delete[] plnml;
}

template <typename t>
TabWiel<t>::TabWiel(const TabWiel<t>& tw){
    deg = tw.deg;
    plnml = new t[deg + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < deg + 1; i++)
        plnml[i] = tw.plnml[i];
}

template <typename t>
t& TabWiel<t>::operator [](int s){
    if (s >= 0 && s < deg + 1)
        return plnml[s];
    else
        throw BadIndex(s);
}

template <typename t>
bool TabWiel<t>::operator ==(Wielomian<t>& tw){
    try{
        TabWiel<t>& rhs = dynamic_cast<TabWiel<t>&>(tw);
        if (deg == rhs.deg){
            for (int i = 0; i < deg + 1; i++){
                if (plnml[i] != rhs.plnml[i])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (const bad_cast& e){
        cerr << "An exception" << e.what() << " thrown." << endl;
    }
}

template <typename t>
ostream& operator <<(ostream& s, TabWiel<t>& tw){
    for (int i = 0; i < tw.deg + 1; i++){
        if (i != tw.deg)
            s << tw.plnml[i] << "x^" << i << "+";
        else
            s << tw.plnml[i] << "x^" << i << endl;
    }
    return s;
}

template <typename t>
TabWiel<t>& TabWiel<t>::operator +(Wielomian<t>& tw){
    try{
        TabWiel<t>& rhs = dynamic_cast<TabWiel<t>&>(tw);
        if (rhs.deg <= deg){
            for (int i = 0; i < rhs.deg + 1; i++)
                plnml[i] = plnml[i] + rhs.plnml[i];
            return *this;
        }
        else{
            t* tmp = new t[deg + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < deg + 1; i++)
                tmp[i] = plnml[i];
            int tmp_deg = deg;
            delete[] plnml;
            deg = rhs.deg;
            plnml = new t[deg + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < deg + 1; i++){
                if(i < tmp_deg + 1)
                    plnml[i] = tmp[i] + rhs.plnml[i];
                else
                    plnml[i] = rhs.plnml[i];
            }
            return *this;
        }
    }
    catch (const bad_cast& e){
        cerr << "An exception" << e.what() << " thrown." << endl;
    }
}

template <typename t>
TabWiel<t>& TabWiel<t>::operator +=(Wielomian<t>& tw){
    try{
        TabWiel<t>& rhs = dynamic_cast<TabWiel<t>&>(tw);
        TabWiel<t>* nowy = new TabWiel<t>;
        TabWiel<t> copy;
        copy = *this;
        *nowy = copy + rhs;
        return *nowy;
    }
    catch (const bad_cast& e){
        cerr << "An exception" << e.what() << " thrown." << endl;
    }
}
```

I wish the assignment of `*p` to non-empty subclass object worked. But it doesn't - all the code does, is that it enters "Wielomian" definition and then proceeds to the next line of the `main` function (which in my case is the last line).

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean?  Did you get an error message?  Did it refuse to compile?

Comment: I didn't do anything. I ran a debugger and followed it line by line. It just entered abstract's class definition and that's it.

Comment: What behavior did you expect?

Comment: I thought *p will be a copy of s1.

Comment: What did it actually turn out to be?

Comment: [More information needed.](https://ideone.com/jyQgzY)

Comment: This I'm not sure. All I know is that s1, in my case, had some data stored and after the assignment *p should to. But it was "empty" so to say.

Comment: By empty, you mean...

Comment: Should I provide you with my code?

Comment: I thought you already did.  Yeah, show us the whole thing.

Comment: You need [virtual operators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/669894/4538344).

Comment: Ok, I will show you my code fully.

Comment: And I did. There are basically two classes: "Wielomian" which is an abstract class for a polynomial and "TabWiel" - a polynomial in an array.

Comment: Read about "c++ slicing", to understand what you think you want to accomplish.  Don't do slicing things.

Comment: If p doesn't contain members of s1, why would you expect that to change after assigning s1 to p?

Comment: This question is very interesting, because unlike traditional slicing errors (Class=Subclass) here the target is in reality a Subclass and slicing occurs only because dereferencing.  There is a solution by creating a custom operator= using a virtual clone function in a double dispatch construct.

Comment: This question is about copy constructors, but it should be the same for the copy operator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731217/how-to-copy-create-derived-class-instance-from-a-pointer-to-a-polymorphic-base-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very interesting.

First of all, your code doesn't work because of [slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing):  you have two objects of `Subclass`, but 
the compiler thinks that one of it is only a `Class`. So the code generated copies only the common 
part of the data.

To demonstrate this, let's ellaborate on  gha.st 's initial code extract:

```
struct Class { int a; virtual void hugo() = 0; };
struct Subclass : Class { int b; void hugo() override { cout<<"sub"<<a<<b<<endl; } };
int main() {
    Class* p = new Subclass;
    static_cast<Subclass*>(p)->a = 2; 
    static_cast<Subclass*>(p)->b = 3; 
    Subclass s1;
    s1.a = 4; s1.b=5;
    *p = s1;  // slicing !!  
    p->hugo();
    return 0;
}
```

What happens here ?  Well, `b` member isn't copied, although `*p` is in reality a `Subclass` !

But `*p` is still a `Subclass`,  so we could use polymorphism to get this work. The trick is to use an virtual `clone()` member to clone 
an object (the object shall know its own type) into a target, if the target has the same type.
Then you could define `operator=()` for `Class` to use this `clone()`.  This makes it handy to use, but the drawback is that you'll no longer 
be able to rely on default `operator=` for any descendent of `Class` if you want to avoid an endless recursion.

Here the proof of concept:

```
struct Class {
    int a; 
    virtual void hugo() = 0; 
    virtual bool clone(Class*t) = 0; 
    Class& operator=(Class& o) {
        if (!o.clone(this)) {  // try to clone on subclass on a target of same subclass
            // here,the source and target might differ. Only common members can be copied
            a = o.a; 
        }
        return *this; 
    }
};
struct Subclass : Class {
    int a,b; 
    void hugo() override { cout<<"sub"<<a<<b<<endl; } 
    bool clone(Class*t) { 
        cout<<"Clone "; 
        if (dynamic_cast<Subclass*>(t)) {  // if source and target of same subclass
             //*dynamic_cast<Subclass*>(t) = *this;  // this doesn't work cause default operator will try to copy the Class base, causing recursion
             dynamic_cast<Subclass*>(t)->a = a;   // copy members
             dynamic_cast<Subclass*>(t)->b = b;
             return true; 
        }
        else return false; // or tell that class of source and target are different. 
    } 
};
```

Then you can use the main() function above, and see that the object is properly copied.

This trick is a kind of simplified [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch). You could even elaborate further by foreseing various kind of conversions depending on source and target subtype.