# Is there a mechanism in C++ to make a full copy of a derived class from a base class pointer without dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, auto

Consider the following example, where object slicing occurs during dereference of a base pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Base {
  public:
    virtual void hello() {
        printf("hello world from base\n");
    }
};
class Derived : public Base{
  public:
    virtual void hello() {
        printf("hello world from derived\n");
    }
};

int main(){
    Base * ptrToDerived = new Derived;
    auto d = *ptrToDerived;
    d.hello();
}
```

I want the variable `d` to hold an object of type `Derived` instead of an object of type `Base`, without dynamic memory allocation, and without an explicit cast.

I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731217/how-to-copy-create-derived-class-instance-from-a-pointer-to-a-polymorphic-base-c), but the solution proposed in the answer requires dynamic memory allocation, because it returns a pointer to the new object, instead of the value of the  new object.

**Is this possible in C++11?**

Comment: Can you limit your class hierarchy in some way? If there's a bounded number of types, you could go with `boost::variant`. If you could limit the maximum possible size of an object to a reasonable value, you could create a smart pointer-like class to manage it.

Comment: @milleniumbug, In practice the derived class is a templated class, so I don't think I can bound it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible, because if `d` does not have dynamic storage duration, then it must have static, thread, or automatic storage duration, and in all of those cases, the type of the object is known at compile time. In your case, you want the type of the object to be determined at runtime, since `ptrToDerived` may point to a `Base` object or a `Derived` object or to an object of some other class derived from `Base`.

If your concern is about lifetime and memory leaks, just have `clone` return a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` instead of `Base*`.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I am avoiding dynamic memory allocation for performance reasons.

Comment: @merlin2011: Look into a variant (e.g., `boost::variant`) that can store one of many of your derived classes in a block of memory. This forces you to statically know which derived classes you might want, of course.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you mean that you want `auto` to deduce to `D`.

However this is not possible: all types must be known at compile-time. Imagine if the code were:

```
Base *b = some_func();
auto d = *b;
```

There's no way the compiler can know the dynamic type of what `b` points to, because it might not be decided until runtime.