# C++ copy a derived class object from pointer to another

Tags: c++, pointers, copy, clone

Let's say I have this base class for a data container:

```
class BaseClass{
public:
    int a;

    int getA();
    void setA(int newA);
}
```

And I have a derived class:

```
class DerivedClass : BaseClass{
public:
    int b;

    int getB();
    void setB(int newB);
}
```

Now I create two instances of the derived class:

```
DerivedClass* first = new DerivedClass();
DerivedClass* second = new DerivedClass();
```

**Ok, here is my question:**
How can I let *second* point to a deep copy of *first*s object (without producing a memory leak)?

Also, I have to consider that the class / function which handles both pointers and wants to copy them isn't aware of the exact inheritated class. So those pointers could also point to another inheritance of *BaseClass*, and the copy function has to work still and copy **all!** members.

Comment: Can you give a more complete example? This doesn't give us a lot of information on `derivedClass` or what it's derived from.

Comment: `derivedClass x = *new derivedClass();` memory leak...

Comment: There is no pointer slicing involved, there is convoluted usage of objects by value with memory leaks

Comment: What do you intend by `x= *new ...`? That asterisk...

Comment: Typically solved with a `clone` method. Remember that different objects derived from the base will have different sizes and shapes. The best base can do is slice.

Comment: "Is there a way to fix this?" yes use virtual function(s)

Comment: `*b = *a` will call `baseClass::operator=(const baseClass&)`. At this point your code doesn't know that it's dealing with `derivedClasses`.

Comment: derivedClass x = *new derivedClass(); Are you sure it will be compiled ? derivedClass *x = new derivedClass();  baseClass *a = x; - this will work;  &x taking address of variable . Pointer is an integer e.g. unsigned long or unsigned long long e.g. size_t variable with the meaning - memory address. So &x result will be  derivedClass * *

Comment: To elaborate on what @user4581301 said, suppose you have two different derived types, and `a` points to an object of one derived type and `b` points to an object of the other derived type. What should `*b = *a` do?

Comment: @VictorGubin there is dereference there `derivedClass x = *new derivedClass();` as OP thinks that if he puts `new` somewhere it would work like pointers but there is no difference than `derivedClass x` rather than memory leak

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy/create derived class instance from a pointer to a polymorphic base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731217/how-to-copy-create-derived-class-instance-from-a-pointer-to-a-polymorphic-base-c)

Comment: Handy reading: [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new).

Comment: @Slava I didn't meant x and y as pointers but a and b

Comment: And why does this lead to a memory leak? Shouldn't I use the dereference?

Comment: You should not use `new` there at all, or if you do need dynamically allocated object use smart pointers. Every call to `new` must be accompanied with `delete`

Comment: In `derivedClass x = *new derivedClass();`, `new derivedClass()` allocates space for a `derivedClass` in Dynamic storage (probably a heap), constructs a `derivedClass` in that space, and returns a pointer to it. This object is then copied into another `derivedClass` being constructed in Automatic storage (probably a stack). You keep the copy as `x`, but the pointer to dynamically allocated object is discarded, making it next to impossible to later `delete` to fee up the allocation. This is the leak.

Comment: You could get the effect you need without the leak with `derivedClass x;`. You might want, and been trying to get, something else, but you don't need it.

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
derivedClass x = *new derivedClass();
derivedClass y = *new derivedClass();
```

is a convoluted way to say:

```
derivedClass x = derivedClass();
derivedClass y = derivedClass();
```

putting `new` there only creates a memory leak and does not make `x` or `y` any different and would not make them "pointers" as you think. As for this:

```
*b = *a;
```

to work properly you should use a virtual function instead:

```
class Derived {
public:
    virtual void copy_to( Base &b ) const override
    {
        if( Derived *d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>( &b ) ) 
            *d = *this;
    }
```

and call it like this:

```
 a->copy_to( *b );
```

Of course `copy_to` needs to be defined and implemented in the base and every derived class.