# How should I write the constructor for my class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a container class to which i can send a Geometry object as constructor argument.

Geometry is a polymorphic class as interface for other geometric types like Sphere and Rectangle.

My question is that in Container class the constructor with arguments "Container(std::string str, Geometry* geometry)" can i code this in more flexible manner.

Whenever i will add a new SubClass to Geometry than i would need to write another IF condtion in Container class Constructor.

```
include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include "Container.h"
#include "Geometry.h"
#include "Sphere.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "Container.h"

int main()
{
    const char* fileName = "saved.txt"; 
    Sphere sph;
    Rectangle rect;
    Container contSphere("ABC", &sph);
    Container contRectangle("DEF", &rect);
    Sphere* s = (Sphere*)contSphere.getGeomtry();
    s->PrintGeom();
    Rectangle* r = (Rectangle*)contRectangle.getGeomtry();
    r->PrintGeom(); 
    do
    {
        std::cout << '\n' << "Press a key to continue...";
    } while (std::cin.get() != '\n');
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
class Geometry
{
private:
    std::string stdstringGeom;
    std::string stdstrType;

public:

    Geometry() : stdstringGeom("GeometyrString"), stdstrType("Geometry") {}
    virtual ~Geometry() {}


    virtual std::string getType()
    {
        return stdstrType;
    }

     virtual void  PrintGeom()
    {
        std::cout << "geometry virtual function";
    }

};
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
#pragma once

#include "Geometry.h"
class Sphere : public Geometry
{
private:
    std::string stdstrSphere;
    std::string stdstrType;


public:
    Sphere() : Geometry() ,  stdstrSphere( "DefaultSphere") , stdstrType("Sphere") {}
    Sphere( std::string str) : Geometry() ,  stdstrSphere(str) , stdstrType("Sphere"){}
    void PrintGeom()
    {
        std::cout << "Sphere Virtual Function" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string getType()
    {
        return stdstrType;
    }

};
```

///////////////// Defination for Constructor class////////////////////

```
#include "Geometry.h"
#include "Sphere.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"

class Container
{
private:
    std::string stdstrCont;
    Geometry* geom;

public:
    Container() : stdstrCont("NoName") { geom = new Geometry; }
    Container(std::string str, Geometry* geometry) : stdstrCont(str)
    {
    // I am doing this to avoid slicing and i want to do a deep copy.   
     if (geometry->getType() == "Sphere")
        {
            Sphere* sph = (Sphere*)geometry;
            geom = new Sphere(*sph);
        }
        else if (geometry->getType() == "Rectangle")
        {
            Rectangle* rec = (Rectangle*)geometry;
            geom = new Rectangle(*rec);

        }
    }

    ~Container()
    {
        if (geom != nullptr)
            delete geom;
    }

    Geometry* getGeomtry()
    {
        return geom;
    }

    void PrintContainer()
    {
        std::cout << stdstrCont;
    }
};
```

Comment: 1) Why are you using `Container`, and not simply `std::vector<Geometry*>`?  Or better yet `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Geometry>>`?  2) if you're going to store raw pointers in a container, your base class `Geometry` better have a virtual destructor, otherwise calling `delete geom;` leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes my base class does have a virtual destructor , i simplied this code and kept the relevent details only for the question.

Comment: You decided to eliminate one of the most important part of the code, a part of the code that could influence what answers you get and/or throw persons down the wrong path of trying to answer your question.

Comment: Closely related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148706/copying-a-polymorphic-object-in-c

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i have updated the code with virtual destructor for geometry.

Comment: *My question is that in Container class the constructor with arguments "`Container(std::string str, Geometry* geometry)`" is it the correct way to code it.*  "correct" is a vague word, there can be different standards to determine whether something is "correct"

Comment: @L.F i mean can i have a better method than this as it is quite raw if i add a new Subclass to the geometry than i have again change the code in container class.

Comment: Ah, September....

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit ???

Comment: @Sam The time of year when this question is posted some 20, 30 times per week :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is all backward, and a consequence is that you are making the `Container` responsible for working out the type of all `Geometry` objects passed to it, in order to copy them.   That will make your `Container` a maintenance nightmare - if someone creates another class derived from `Geometry`, they can forget to modify `Container` accordingly.

You've also omitted code that is relevant to your question (like virtual destructors) and included code that is irrelevant to the question (declaration of `std::string` members, and initialisation of them in constructors, and other virtual functions).

Instead, it would be better to make the class `Geometry`, and its derived classes, responsible for copying themselves.

At heart would be the `Geometry` class itself

```
 #include <memory>     // for std::unique_ptr
 class Geometry
 {
    public:
        Geometry() {};
        virtual ~Geometry() = default;

         virtual std::unique_ptr<Geometry> Clone() const = 0;
 };
```

(I've omitted the `std::string` members for convenience).   The derived classes then override the `Clone()` function, viz;

```
 class Sphere: public Geometry
 {
    public:
        Sphere() : Geometry() {};
         ~Sphere() = default;

         std::unique_ptr<Geometry> Clone() const {return std::unique_ptr<Geometry>(new Sphere(*this));}; 
 };

 // similarly for other shapes
```

The `Clone()` function is pure virtual in `Geometry`, so the derived classes cannot be instantiated unless you remember to override it.

The responsibility for cloning rests with `Geometry` and its derived classes - and the compiler will helpfully diagnose an error if a class is derived from `Geometry` that does not override the `Clone()` function.

Then, all a `Container` needs to do is have a member `std::unique_ptr<Geometry>` or (if you intend to have a set of them) a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Geometry> >`.
For the case where the `Container` only needs a single `Geometry`, the definition of `Container` might be

```
 class Container
 {
       public:
            Container() : geom() {};
            Container(Geometry *p) : geom(p->Clone()) {};
            Container(const Container &c) : geom(c.geom->Clone()) {};
            Container &operator=(const Container &c)
            {
                  geom = c.geom->Clone();   // this will release the existing c.geom
                  return *this;
            };
            ~Container() = default;
       private:

             std::unique_ptr<Geometry> geom;
 };
```

The reason I've used `std::unique_ptr<Geometry>` in the above (instead of `Geometry *` as in your code) is that `std::unique_ptr<>` avoids the need to explicitly decide when to destroy a `Geometry` object.

The no-argument constructor of `Container` initialises to containing a null `Geometry` (i.e. a null pointer).

The constructor of `Container` that accepts a `Geometry *` clones the passed object, and does not assume ownership of it.   This means the caller is responsible for the lifetime of the object it passes.   This is consistent with your `main()`, which constructs objects of automatic storage duration.

Note that I'm following the "rule of three" - if a non-default version of a copy constructor, copy assignment, or destructor  is defined, then the other two should also be defined.    The `operator=()` in the above works in a manner consistent with the copy constructor  (i.e. it clones objects in the `Container`, rather than causing `Geometry` objects to be shared between `Container`s).    The destructor is explicitly defined as the default, since the `Container` is not explicitly managing lifetime of its members (the destructor of `std::unique_ptr` does the work).

Comment: Error C2440 'return': cannot convert from 'Sphere *' to 'std::unique_ptr<Geometry,std::default_delete<_Ty>>'

Comment: Yeah, okay.   Modified to fix.   Forgot to do an explicit conversion.

Comment: i am facing the same problem here also  Container(Geometry *p) : geom(p->Clone()) {};

Comment: even if i try to cast it geom = (Geometry*)geometry->Clone(); , still the error persists.

Comment: Or should i return Geometry* from the clone function.

Comment: I can't reproduce that one.      All variants of the `Clone()` function I've shown return `std::unique_ptr<Geometry>`, and I haven't named any variable `geometry`.    Don't cast to a raw pointer.

Comment: C2440 'type cast': cannot convert from 'std::unique_ptr<Geometry,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' to 'Geometry *'

Comment: on this line geom = geometry->Clone();

Comment: You presumably have given `geom` a type `Geometry *`.   If you look in my answer, it has a type `std::unique_ptr<Geometry>`.

Comment: i am talking avout this line Container(Geometry *p) : geom(p->Clone()) {};

Comment: C2440 'type cast': cannot convert from 'std::unique_ptr<Geometry,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' to 'Geometry *'

Comment: If you look at the definition I gave for the `Container`, the ONLY usage of a raw pointer is for the type of argument to a constructor  (`Container(Geometry *p)`).   There is no other raw pointer used in that class at all - everything else uses `unique_ptr`.    If you are trying to use raw pointers anywhere else, you will break the logic of what I gave you .... as, it seems, your compiler is telling you.

Comment: if i want to use as Geometry* instead of unique_ptr can i do that as i have work on existing code and it has Geometry*

Comment: You can, but then you need to remember to explicitly manage the lifetime of objects e.g. `delete` objects when no longer needed in the destructor of `Container` (which then cannot be a `default`).   I would recommend AGAINST that, as it's easy to make an error in that, not clean up as you intend when exceptions  are thrown, etc.    (Before C++11, I'd recommend `std::auto_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr` - and still not use raw pointers).

Comment: Don't use `std::auto_ptr`. Ever. At all.