# Copy a derived class with only a base class pointer in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy

I'm trying to make a copy of a derived class with only a base class pointer.

So if I have:

```
class BaseClass; //Abstract class with =0 functions
class LeftClass : BaseClass;
class RightClass : BaseClass;
```

And I have a function that takes a BaseClass as a parameter:

```
void Function(BaseClass* baseClass)
```

I want to make a copy of BaseClass, but I want to also copy the extended functionality of LeftClass *OR* RightClass, but I don't know which one was passed to the function - both are possible.

So I have something like this:

```
//global
vector<BaseClass*> myVector;

void Function(BaseClass* baseClass)
{
   BaseClass* baseClassCopy = new BaseClass(baseClass);
   myVector.push_back(baseClassCopy);
}
```

And then I call the function with a left or right class

```
int main()
{
   LeftClass leftClass;
   Function(&leftClass);
   LeftClass* ResultOfCopy = myVector.at(0);
}
```

That code doesn't copy over the entire leftclass as a copy, is there a way to do this I'm overlooking?

Also `BaseClass` is abstract, some of the functions are `=0` so I can't new one up. Otherwise there is a copy function in the other classes to use.

Comment: Looks like you need the [clone functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5148751/4342498)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without modifying any of the classes? I'm unit testing, so I'm not supposed to change any code...

Comment: Oh wait I might have a solution from that. Thanks! :)

Comment: Wait, what if the BaseClass is abstract so I can't 'new' a new one?

Comment: @Sam Even if you could, it would `new` the wrong class. You fundamentally *need* to add a `clone` method (“virtual copy constructor”) to your class to obtain this functionality, short of cheating the way Nathan’s answer shows (but, really, don’t do that).

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change any of the classes to add a clone function then you can manually do that yourself by using `dynamic_cast` to determine its run time type and call the correct derived constructor.  That would look like

```
void Function(BaseClass* baseClass)
{
    if (auto ptr = dynamic_cast<LeftClass*>(baseClass))
        myVector.push_back(new LeftClass(*ptr));
    if (auto ptr = dynamic_cast<RightClass*>(baseClass))
        myVector.push_back(new RightClass(*ptr)); 
}
```

and you can see it working in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/671e23062921cffa)

Comment: Got it, thanks. I can't upvote comments or solutions yet though, new to SO. :)

Comment: @Sam No worries.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problem is usually solved by a `clone()` method.

```
class BaseClass
{
    virtual BaseClass* clone()            = 0
};

class LeftClass: public BaseClass
{
    virtual LeftClass* clone() override {return new LeftClass(*this);}
};
class RightClass: public BaseClass
{
    virtual RightClass* clone() override {return new RightClass(*this);}
};
class RightRightClass: public RightClass
{
    virtual RightRightClass* clone() override {return new RightRightClass(*this);}
};
```

Your function is now easy to write:

```
void Function(BaseClass* baseClass)
{
   BaseClass* baseClassCopy = !baseClass ? nullptr : baseClass->clone();
   myVector.push_back(baseClassCopy);
}
```

Comment: This will still create an object of type `BaseClass` though, which does not solve the issue of 'copying the functionality of LeftClass or RightClass'

Comment: @TheGoldKnight23 No. This will create an object of the correct type but return a pointer of `BaseClass` that points at the object of the correct type. Notice the calls to `new`:  `return new LeftClass(*this);` and `return new RightClass(*this);`

Comment: But you will not be able to access the functionality of `LeftClass` or `RightClass` through that pointer, although I see your point that _technically_ it does copy it and return the correct object (which is why `dynamic_cast` works)

Comment: @TheGoldKnight23 Yes you will!! The Note: `BaseClass` is a virtual base class. The functions you want to access are virtual methods that are overrideen in the derived class. So you have full access to these.

Comment: Right sorry, though they meant access members not declared in `BaseClass`. Yes of course that works but why use `dynamic_cast` with run-time cost when you can use templates that are compile-time cost?

Comment: @TheGoldKnight23 OK. That is an interesting question. 1. I think `clone()` is usually the result of other bad design decisions that have backed you into a corner. 2. I think dynamic_cast is a bad solution as it is very brittle (but that is solved by using explicit virtual methods that removes the need for explicit manual casts). 3 Why pay the runtime cost?  Never do that if you can help it. **BUT** you can't always determine at compile time the actual runtime type. In this case your method only works because the user took an automatic variable.

Comment: What happened if the call was `Function(my_vector[0])` ie. make a copy of an object that already exists in the vector. You can't tell the runtime type as you only have a base class pointer. In this case your code would break as you make a copy of the base class not a copy of the underlying type.

Comment: Damn I did not think that, (`Function(my_vector[0])` thats a bloody good point, Ill update my answer to reflect that. You are wrong about `auto` though, I could equally have used the template `BC*`, auto is compile time anyway and would likely be chosen as `BasicClass` by the compiler without the template

Comment: You can use [covariant return types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual#Covariant_return_types) to return the corresponding pointers `virtual LeftClass* clone() override {return new LeftClass(*this);}`

Comment: @L.F. Thanks for the link. I had suspected that was the case but did not have a reference to confirm it.