# Is it possible to support polymorphic method calls at the same time as abstracting pointers away from users?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, polymorphism, smart-pointers

## The problem

I'm trying to support some degree of polymorphism in my code. I basically want to override a method `str` in subclasses (`Dog` and `Duck`) and then use a smart pointer to the superclass `Animal` in another class (`AnimalContainer`) to call the `str` method. Specifically, I want to support the following API:

```
int main(){
    Duck duck;
    Dog dog;

    AnimalContainer duckInContainer(duck);
    std::cout << duckInContainer.str() << std::endl; // Outputs "None" but should output "Duck"


    AnimalContainer dogInContainer(dog);
    std::cout << dogInContainer.str() << std::endl; // Outputs "None" but should output "Dog"
}
```

The lack of pointers here is deliberate. I'm intending this to be a front end of an API and want to make it as simple as possible. Therefore, if possible, I want to avoid making users explicitely create (say) a `Dog` pointer themselves. In other words, I'd like to *avoid* making users do something like this:

```
Dog dog;
std::unique_ptr<Dog> dog_ptr = std::make_unique<Dog>(dog);
AnimalContainer animalContainer(dog_ptr)
std::cout << animalContainer.str() << std::endl;
```

Is the above possible and if so, what changes do I need to make to the following code:

## The code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;


class Animal {

public:
    Animal() = default;

    virtual std::string str() {
        return "None";
    }

};

class Duck : public Animal {
public:
    using Animal::Animal;

    std::string str() override {
        return "Duck";
    }
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    using Animal::Animal;

    std::string str() override {
        return "Dog";
    }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<Animal> AnimalPtr;


class AnimalContainer {
private:
    AnimalPtr animal_ptr;
public:
    explicit AnimalContainer(const Animal& animal){
        this->animal_ptr = std::make_unique<Animal>(animal);
    }

    explicit AnimalContainer(AnimalPtr animal_ptr){
        this->animal_ptr = std::make_unique<Animal>(*animal_ptr);
    }

    std::string str(){
        return this->animal_ptr->str();
    }

};
```

So far I think that this line

```
this->animal_ptr = std::make_unique<Animal>(animal);
```

is the issue since the `Dog` or `Duck` is being sliced to an `Animal`. However, the alternative which is being explicit about which type of Animal we want in the pointer aka

```
std::unique_ptr<Dog> dog_ptr = std::make_unique<Dog>(Dog())
```

Comment: What abaout ````AnimalPtr aptr = std::make_unique<Dog>(Dog())````?

Comment: You're `AnimalContainer` constructor is taking an object and making a copy of it, but only using the base class which results in the slice.  You'll want to [add clone methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148706/copying-a-polymorphic-object-in-c) to your hierarchy.

Comment: And then `clone` in the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without clone function, you might do:

```
class AnimalContainer {
private:
    AnimalPtr animal_ptr;
public:
    explicit AnimalContainer(const Dog& dog){
        this->animal_ptr = std::make_unique<Dog>(dog);
    }
    // Same for Duck

    explicit AnimalContainer(AnimalPtr animal_ptr){
        this->animal_ptr = std::move(animal_ptr));
    }

    std::string str(){ return this->animal_ptr->str(); }
};
```

Or more generically:

```
class AnimalContainer {
private:
    AnimalPtr animal_ptr;
public:
    template <typename T>
    explicit AnimalContainer(const T& animal){
        this->animal_ptr = std::make_unique<T>(animal);
    }

    explicit AnimalContainer(AnimalPtr animal_ptr){
        this->animal_ptr = std::move(animal_ptr));
    }

    std::string str(){ return this->animal_ptr->str(); }
};
```