# member vector with base class pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, raii, copy-assignment

I have a class with a vector as below:

```
#include <vector>

class Base{};

class Derived: public Base{};

class Foo{
   private:
        std::vector<Base*> vec;
   public:
        Foo() = default;
        void addObject(const Base* b){
        // vec.push_back(new Base(*b));
        // vec.push_back(new Derived(*b));
        }
};

int main(){
        Derived* d = new Derived();
        Base* b = new Base();
        Foo f;
        f.addObject(d);
        f.addObject(b);
        
        delete d;
        delete b;
        return 0;
}
```

The function **addBase** may receive **Derived's pointers**. The line *vec.push_back(new Base(b));* is expected to use b's copy to initialize a new object whose pointer will be *pushed_back*. If I don't use new, I will have resources shared between b and the vector(**This is a sin**).

I want to maintain polymorphism. How do I ensure objects that are pushed back maintain the type they were assigned during their creation without forcing everything into a Base object.

Comment: I have absolutely no clue, what you're asking about. Do you have any problems with that code you posed?

Comment: [Mcve] might clarify, no idea otherwise

Comment: If you want `addBase` to add a pointer to an existing object, just drop the `const` and `new` from everything. If you want `addBase` to actually create a copy of the pointed-to object before adding it to `vec`, take a look at [this idiom for copying polymorphic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148706/copying-a-polymorphic-object-in-c)

Comment: _"the code above just about captures the main issue"_ -- no it doesn't.  There is zero polymorphism in your code.  Additionally, you cannot push a `const Base*` into a vector that stores non-const `Base*`.  The compiler should rightfully be emitting an error regarding the loss of const type qualifier if you try to do it.  You can convert from non-const to const, but not the other way.

Comment: @NathanPierson
I think your solution may work. If I am getting it right, I should implement a virtual function that returns a new object of the same type as the calling object.

Comment: No, the solution is to determine whether `Foo` should be storing `const Base*` values or `Base*` values.  We have no idea of the required semantics for your program.  If it should store const values, then change the vector to `std::vector<const Base*>`.  If it should store non-const values, then change the function to `void addObject(Base*)`.  In both scenarios, I assume you want the "add" function to simply store the pointer: `vec.push_back(b);` ...

Comment: ... If instead you need it to store a _copy_, that is more complex and requires that your base class provides `virtual Base* copy()` which then every subclass overrides.  And then of course `Foo` would need to manage that memory with an appropriate destructor (and Rule of Three considerations), or perhaps use `std::unique_ptr` to manage these copies.

Comment: It needs to store a copy. As noted in my previous comment to @NathanPierson, I accepted the solution to have a virtual clone function in every derived class. I already have a destructor for the necessary clean up.

Comment: Side note: You most likely want a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>`. Otherwise the code will leak memory all over the place. There is rarely a case in which a container of raw pointers makes sense. (It only makes sense when the container doesn’t *own* the pointed-at objects.)

Comment: I agree with using ```std::unique_ptr```. I had used raw since I had a destructor for the cleanup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a clone of the object passed to `addObject`, you have essentially two options. 1) Have a virtual function `clone` in `Base` and `Derived`, or better 2) let the copy constructor handle it.

If you go for the second option, `addObject` need to the know the actual type of the passed object. This could be done with a template:

```
template <class T>
void addObject(const T * t)
{
  Base *b = new T(*t);
}
```

In a robust program we don't want to use `new`/`delete` but rather `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. Passing `t` as a reference, rater than pointer, is also considered a better practice.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>


class Base
{
public:
  virtual void cname() { std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;}
};


class Derived: public Base
{
public:
  virtual void cname() { std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;}
};
 

class Foo
{
private:
  // You may switch to `std::shared_ptr` if that better fits your use case
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> > vec;
public:
  template <class T>
  void addObject(const T & t)
  {
    vec.push_back(std::make_unique<T> (t)); 
  }

  void dump()
  {
    for (auto &bp: vec)
      bp->cname();
  }
};

int main(){
  Derived d;
  Base b;

  Foo f;
  f.addObject(d);
  f.addObject(b);

  f.dump();
  
  return 0;
}
```

Naturally for this to work, the reference passed to `addObject` must be of the correct type. This will create a clone of type `Base`, not `Derived`:

```
Derived d;
Base &e = d;
f.addObject(e);
```

Comment: The second approach is interesting. I am using raw pointers to avoid the overhead of shared_ptr. Unique_ptr won't work since the vector elements will be passed around quite a bit. Besides, there isn't confusion about ownership since the pointers are all owned by the class objects hence can be deleted by the destructor. Does this logic make sense to you?

Comment: I have also noticed that the second approach works for a function but will not work for the copy constructor of Foo

Comment: @Shwalala In general, if your vector owns the pointed-to objects then it should hold some kind of smart pointer.  If you later pass those pointers to something that doesn't take ownership then you pass a raw pointer.  If you maintain the "smart pointer == owner, raw pointer == non-owner" dynamic you'll be much less likely to have leaks and/or double-free issues.  That also makes this whole question more-or-less moot, since you can change `addObject` to accept a `unique_ptr<Base>` and be sure that it won't ever share ownership with the caller.

Comment: I get your point. The real problem I was having was in a Copy Constructor and I used this question to remodel it. The second approach doesn't seem to work in the CC. Either way, Unique_ptr may is a good suggestion!

Comment: Note that the behaviour of the example program is undefined. To fix it, make the destructor of `Base` virtual.