# Copy constructor not behaving as it should?

Tags: c++, stdvector, copy-constructor

I'm creating a program which has an abstract base class called `component`, I have 3 classes `inductor`, `resistor` and `capacitor` which inherit from `components`. I have a vector:

`std::vector<component*> components;`

Which is a member of a class called `circuit`. So `components` contains pointers to `component` objects (whether that be `resistor`, `capacitor` or `inductor`).

Now my problem arises when I try and create a new vector, initialized as so:

`std::vector<component*> temp_components = components;`

Currently the `vector` only contains `resistor` objects, so I have a copy constructor in 'resistor.cpp':

```
resistor::resistor(const resistor& resistor)
{
    impedance = resistor.impedance;
    voltage_frequency = resistor.voltage_frequency;
    name = resistor.name;
    resistance = resistor.resistance;
}
```

And also an assignment operator in `resistor`:

```
resistor& resistor::operator=(resistor& rhs)
{
    //Check if equal
    if (&rhs == this) {
        return *this;
    }

    delete& impedance; delete& voltage_frequency; delete& name; delete& resistance;
    impedance = rhs.impedance;
    voltage_frequency = rhs.voltage_frequency;
    name = rhs.name;
    resistance = rhs.resistance;

    return *this;
}
```

However, when I run the code to create `temp_components` equal to `components`, the pointers in the 2 `vectors` are the same, so when I change a value in `temp_components`, it does the same in `components`, which is not what I want.

I think this is because of the way `vector` works for pointers, but I have no idea where to begin in fixing this problem. I want to make it so the details (class members) of the `component`s which the pointers point to are copied, but the pointers don't both point to the same memory location.

Comment: *"the memory addresses of the 2 vectors are the same"*. This cannot happen in C++. Every object has different address than any other object in the program.

Comment: @AnoopRana I suspect he means that the memory addresses _contained in the vectors_ are the same. Which is to be expected because making a copy of a `std::vector<component*>` will create a separate vector that contains the same _pointers_ as the original vector, not pointers to copies of those elements.

Comment: `std::vector<component*> temp_components = components;` ... This is a vector of pointers. The pointers are copied. They objects they point to will not be.

Comment: @AnoopRana Sorry that was vague of me. When I output say the 1st item of components and 1st item of temp_components, the pointer has the exact same value. I have edited to clarify

Comment: *I think this is because of the way vector works for pointers,* -- A vector does not do anything different for pointers as for any other object.  A pointer is simply a value, and the same value-semantics that vector has for other objects, it has for pointers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148706/copying-a-polymorphic-object-in-c might help.

Comment: @ryani42 -- If your goal is to have the pointers shared, then `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<component>>` is what you may want to use instead of what you have now.

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes, the pointers are copied and not the underlying objects to which those pointers point, which i think is no surprise in this case.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It sounds like the intention is that the new vector should actually have different pointed-to objects. Sounds like a `component::clone()` method is called for

Comment: If by "memory addresses of the two vectors are the same" you mean "copying the vector of pointers creates a second vector containing the same pointers" rather than "the pointers in the second vector point at clones of objects pointed to by elements of the first vector" then that is EXACTLY what is required to happen.   If you want something different, you need to write explicit code to do it (e.g. write a loop of the form (C++11 and later) `std::vector<component *> temp_components; for (component *element : components) {temp_components.push_back(new component(*element));}`).

Comment: The search term you are looking for is _shallow copy_ vs _deep copy_.

Comment: If you copy a vector of ints, you get two vectors with the same ints. If you copy a vector of pointers, you get two vectors with the same pointers. This should not be a surprise.

Comment: Why does your copy constructor not use an initializer list?

Comment: @Chris: The copy constructor in the question is just doing what the compiler-generated one would do, only without exception safety (which a ctor-initializer-list could help with) and with increased maintenance burden (which the ctor-initializer-list helps not at all).  It should just be removed.  The assignment operator is horribly broken (separately deleting member subobjects) and also needs to be removed, as the compiler-generated one will do fine.

Comment: @BenVoigt Hahaha christ, okay thank you ill get rid of them and go about creating some better ones.

Comment: How about using `union AnyComponent { Component base; Inductor i; Resistor r; Capacitor c; }; std::vector<AnyComponent> v;`? `std::any` or `std::variant` are also possible.