# Achieving polymorphism

Tags: c++, c++17

I have struct A and struct B, how could I achieve polymorhism for this case when I need to store the objects in a vector in f and it has parameter of base class A

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    void virtual print()
    {
        std::cout << "a\n";
    }
};

struct B : public A
{
    
    void print() override
    {
        std::cout << "b\n"; 
    }
};

void f(A& a)
{   
    // here I don't know what kind of object is that's why I use A
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vecA;
    vecA.emplace_back(std::make_unique<A>(a));

    vecA[0]->print();
    // I want to print b
}

int main()
{   
    B b;
    f(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing?r=Saves_AllUserSaves

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so I guess in this example there's no way to do it, since I would need make_unique<B>(a), right ?

Comment: Yes, you need a certain instance of `B`.

Comment: You need a `clone()` method in your base class.

Comment: @WeijunZhou could you please give an example ?

Comment: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/09/08/make-polymorphic-copy-modern-cpp/

Comment: @KeranStones see Jarod's link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are given a reference to a polymorphic `A`, and you need to store a copy of it while preserving the dynamic type, that calls for *cloning*:

```cpp
struct A
{    // don't forget the virtual destructor if you're storing A polymorphically
    virtual ~A() = default;

    void virtual print() const
    {
        std::cout << "a\n";
    }

    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const {
        return std::make_unique<A>(*this);
    }
};

// add the corresponding clone() override in B:
struct B {
    // ...
    std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const override {
        return std::make_unique<B>(*this);
    }
};

// if we're going to copy it, then it should be cosnt&
void f(const A& a)
{   
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vecA;
    vecA.emplace_back(a.clone());
    // prints b
    vecA[0]->print();
}
```

If you always passed `A` around in a `std::unique_ptr`, you could also avoid the whole `clone()` problem and simply do:

```cpp
void f(std::unique_ptr<A> a)
{   
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vecA;
    vecA.push_back(std::move(a));
    // prints b
    vecA[0]->print();
}
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nMT3q1qqn)*

The solution ultimately depends on whether you need to support copying `A`, or whether you can use it as a move-only type.

---

#### See Also

- [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)
- [Copying a Polymorphic object in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5148706/5740428)
- [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/461203/5740428)